# How to loop back to the beginning of a program? Python

Tags: python

I am trying to loop back  to  the beginning of this code after it is done. After option 'C' is pressed, the program should end, (which I am also struggling with). But I want the program to loop to the beginning unless C is pressed. If  'A' or 'B' is pressed, the program should ask the user to enter an option again. This question is different as it has a specific example. I tried looking on Stack Overflow and found similar questions and tried them, but none of them worked out? Not sure why

```
    #input your full name
    def startagain():
     firstName=raw_input("Enter your first name: ")
     middleName=raw_input("Enter your middle name: ")
    lastName=raw_input("Enter your last name: ")
     #select what option you want.
    options=str(raw_input("Type 'A' for printing the length of your name, 
    'B' for printing your initials and 'C' to exit"))
     #prints first, middle and last name

    if (options == "A" or options == "a"):
         print firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName

    #prints your initials
  elif (options == "B" or options == "b"):
         print firstName[0] + "." + middleName[0] + "." + lastName[0] + "."
    #exit
   elif (options == "C" or options == "c"):
       exit()
         print ("OK, bye!")
    #invalid selection
    else:
        print "Invalid selection. Please select A, B, or C."


    if options == "A" or options == "B":
    startagain()
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: All the indentation seems completely messed up (if I attempt to run your code I don't get past the first line). You also _seem_ to have one function to gather user details, present a menu and operate on your menu selection. Perhaps breaking these into separate functions will help you determine where the error lies

Answer (score 0):

remove call to startagain() at end, and put all the code inside a

```
while True:
```

loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common type of program and usually has this structure

```
while True:
    # print instructions for user
    # get his input
    # have a series of if/elif for handling each option
    # the option that indicates exit just does a break statement
    # to break out of loop
```

This addresses your question about looping but there are other issues with your code. If you are a beginner, you should try to spend time and debug your program, and also take a incremental approach to building your program

1. get it working for one time without the loop
2. build up the code a little at a time and make sure each part is working before adding more line
3. perhaps add only one option at a time
4. finally add the loop